# Using no flag options with Cobra Command?

Tags: go, command-line-interface, go-cobra

I have a command with a default option - id. There may be other flags as well, so any of the following could be called.

```
cmd 81313 # 81313 is the ID
cmd -i 81313
cmd -f foo.txt 81313
cmd -i 81313 -f foo.txt
cmd 81313 -f foo.txt
```

What is the correct way to handle this with Cobra command?

Currently, i'm looking at the value for `-i` and if it's empty, reading the values from `cmdArgs` (if there's something in there, and doesn't have a flag, then I'm assuming it's my ID).

However, this seems more than a little error prone -  e.g. what if someone puts down 2 ids.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little unclear about the semantics here: Are `cmd 81313` and `cmd -i 81313` equivalent? If so, why do you need `-i`? It looks like the id is actually a positional parameter, not a command line option. Is `cmd -i 81313 81313` an error? Or is `-i` simply a boolean option, the presence of which means "the first non-option argument is the id"?

Comment: Ah - so `cmd 81313` is a valid command. So (i'm unfamiliar with the terms) it would be both a positional argument and/or the first non-option argument. Does that help?

Comment: I'm still confused. Let me try to simplify my original question, since it seems it wasn't clear: Are `cmd 81313` and `cmd -i 81313` equivalent? If so, what exactly is the purpose of the `-i` option?

Comment: Ah. Yes, they are equivalent. I am new to designing CLIs, so I thought that offering an explicit flag would give people the opportunity to reorder (if they chose).

Comment: So, we're venturing into opinion territory now, but I would suggest you should pick one or the other (that is, either make it an option or make it a positional argument, but not both).

Comment: This is really helpful - i wish there was a more idiomatic way that this is done (and a way to have these discussions on SO). This was quite helpful nonetheless - if you want to write up an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i wish there was a more idiomatic way that this is done

I think there is, and it's the idea I was trying to get across in the comments: don't provide multiple ways of specifying the same option on the command line.

When choosing between a positional argument vs. an option, the question is usually "is this value the thing on which the command is operating?". For example, a command like `rm` operates on files, so files are specified as positional arguments: we don't need to write `rm -f file1 -f file2 -f file3`, etc.

Similarly, the `ssh` command connects to a remote host, so the hostname is a positional argument. Metadata about that connection (the identity to use, the port to use, configuration options, etc) are also specified as command line options instead.

Your question is a little hard to answer because you haven't told us what your command actually does. If the "id" is required for every invocation of `cmd` and if it identifies the thing upon which the command operates, you should probably just make it a positional argument:

```
cmd 81313
```

If there are ever situations in which you do *not* need to specify the ID, then it should be an optional argument:

```
cmd -i 81313
```

There are situations in which you may have "mandatory options", but these are relatively rare.

Comment: terrific advice, thank you!